# Output of fork() calls

Tags: fork

What would be the output of following fork() calls ?

```
func(){
fork();
fork();
fork() && fork() || fork();
fork();
print("Saikacollection\n");
}
```

Can anyone help me in getting the answer to this code as well as some explanations as I am new to OS ? I have found several questions on fork() on SO, but couldn't figure out much.

Comment: One day, i'm gonna make an OS that outputs "Stop the insanity!!" and dies when 4 forks happen with no processing in between.

Comment: Its not a practical example, just an interview question to check the understandings

Comment: The output is *a lot of processes*.

Comment: @nneonneo Can you please elaborate ? how that will happen ?

Comment: @cHao: OS X does pretty well in this regard; forkbombs are usually met with "Resource temporarily unavailable".

Comment: @PrashantSingh: Each `fork()` turns one process into two.  Both will then `fork()` again, and now you have 4.  Then again, and you have 8.  Half of those (the parent processes) will fork *again*, and now you have 12.  Etc.

Comment: @PrashantSingh: I'm kidding. The result is simply that a fairly large number of processes are generated, so you will probably see "Saikacollection" get printed out a bunch of times. I don't really see the point in actually attempting to count how many, and it's a pretty crappy interview question.

Comment: @cHao check out the answer that I have got finally.

Comment: @nneonneo Check out the answer that I have posted

Comment: Fork bomb raid! go to the bomb shelters!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Saikacollection will be printed `40` times as output to the code. This can be explained as follows :-

To understand the output, we need to know following :-

- On successful execution of a fork() call, new child is created. The process creating the child is called `parent process.`
- Fork() call returns `pid` (process identifier) of the child to parent
- Fork() returns `0` to the child process.

[image]

Consider the image shown :-

Convention : All the parents(callers) of the process are written to `left` and marked with a `star`.

```
fork()
```

- At the beginning, we have just 1 process, so a fork() call creates a child. Considering the root of the tree as level 1, we can see at level 2 , we have two processes, parent(left) and child(right) .

  `fork()`
- fork() again further creates `4` such processes, marked as 1, 2, 3, 4. Since all of the four processes will go through similar code structure further, we can say the total number of processes will be `4` times a single process produces

  `fork()&&fork()||fork()`
- Understanding this statement involves, realizing the fact that in C, `&& operator has more precedence than ||`
- Also, if `first` of two operands joined by `&&` goes `wrong`, we `don't check the second`. Similarly, if `first` of the two operands of `||` is `true`, `we don't check the second` operand.
- Consider, the fork() call at 1(marked) node, two processes are created. While the parent gets a positive number(pid) as return, child gets a 0. So, parent executes the second operator, while the child jumps to fork() after || as marked in the figure.
- The execution of `&&fork()` for the parent at 4th level, returns a pid for one process, which terminates, while the child of that step, gets a 0. So, it goes for execution of `||fork()`
- the final `||fork()` call for child of level 5, further produces a process as a result
- So, at the end of the step, we  have 5 leaves(processes) as marked by underlines in the figure.
- Had we done the same for all the three nodes, we could have got `5*4 = 20` processes.

  `fork()`
- Final fork() just `doubles` the number of process available at that step.
- So, total number of processes =   `2*20 = 40`.

Answer (score 1):

Saikacollection is printed 32 times in a new line every time.

Comment: Assuming the OS synchronizes access to stdout between processes.  If it doesn't, you could conceivably end up with "SSSSSSSSSSaaaaSaaaaaiSaaaaiiSSS..."

Comment: Can you explain it a bit please ?

Comment: @user1747039 Shouldn't it be 40 instead of 32. I think you made a mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you want new process to be more independent, you might take a look at exec-* family of funcitons (POSIX) - so you can fork, and then immediately replace the fork process (you can do it, since newly forked process is controlled by you); Or possibly have a look at popen() as well.